# Pandas is not getting installed in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to install the pandas library on my ubuntu machine but it is not getting installed.

```
pip install pandas
pip3 install pandas
```

I have used pip install pandas

```
Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Downloading pandas-0.25.1.tar.gz (12.6MB): 12.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-WzvvgM/pandas/setup.py) egg_info for package pandas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-WzvvgM/pandas/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        import versioneer
      File "versioneer.py", line 1629
        print("Adding sample versioneer config to setup.cfg", file=sys.stderr)
                                                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-WzvvgM/pandas/setup.py", line 21, in <module>

    import versioneer

  File "versioneer.py", line 1629

    print("Adding sample versioneer config to setup.cfg", file=sys.stderr)

                                                              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-WzvvgM/pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /home/user508/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: What is `python -V` and `pip --version`?

Comment: Looks like installing for Python 2 to me - `pandas>=0.25` dropped support for Python 2.7 and all Python 3 versions before 3.5, so use `pip install "pandas<0.25"` for that matter.

Comment: I think that use `pipenv` or `virtualvenv` can avoid this problem.

Answer (score 6):

From the error log it is clear that the OP is using an unsupported version of python. That is the reason why PIP is trying to install pandas using `pandas-0.25.1.tar.gz` file.

Another hint is in this line,

```
print("Adding sample versioneer config to setup.cfg", file=sys.stderr)
                                                          ^
```

which is giving

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This error clearly indicates that OP is using **Python 2.x**. The above print statement is that of Python 3.x and it returns error when used in **Python 2.x**. See this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/BrownBrokenInstructions) for example.

---

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library has dropped support for python version **< 3.5.3**. See the supported versions from their official [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#python-version-support). It states,

> Officially Python 3.5.3 and above, 3.6, and 3.7.

According to their PyPI [page](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/0.24.1/),

The most recent version which supports python version **< 3.5.3** is **0.24.2**.

You can install it using the below command.

```
pip install pandas==0.24.2
```

> ***Python 2.7*** will reach the end of its life on ***January 1st, 2020***. Please **upgrade** your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date.

Comment: Just a note: the pandas installation requires numpy, and you will need a version compatible with python 2.x as well. I believe `pip install numpy==1.16.3` gives you the most up-to-date version compatible with Python 2.x.